# Does breaking concentration of the slow spell break its effects immediately?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, concentration

On your turn, you break the concentration of an (enemy) [slow](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/slow) spell with your weapon attack.

When exactly does the spell stop affecting you?

At the same moment that the enemy spellcaster loses the concentration or the next turn? Phrased differently: do you get back your extra attacks, your bonus action, and the second half of your movement right away - on the same turn?

Comment: Possible duplicate of: [If a Slow spell ends due to a failed concentration (CON) saving throw, does the attacker get to make any remaining attacks?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/165913/52137) (If it is, no worries, this question will help others find that one)

Comment: Related: "[When using dispel magic to remove slow, when do the effects of slow end?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/95889)"

Comment: I've closed your question as I felt the linked one answered it, but if you feel it does not feel free to [edit] and explain why. Your questions can always be reopened if the need arises